# Load Testing Scenario for upload/download file to/from sftp server using winscp client on Azure

Tags: ssh, sftp, load-testing, winscp

We have Azure (Microsoft cloud), we have installed winscp to upload and download files to SFTP server but performance is too much low, it takes more than enough time to upload and download 50-100 MB files. After discussing with SFTP server team, they have pointed that server does not have any performance issue as other clients are not facing this issue.

a) We need to test performance of SFTP client (WinSCP) on our Azure (Microsoft cloud) VM. Winscp connects to SFTP server and it uploads/downloads files to/from it.

b) Can performance of sftp server be measured at our end? We have to be sure that all is well at server's end because our client is also installed on cloud.

What should I do to achieve this? I found sftp load testing can be done using jmeter but I am not sure how it is going to measure performance of winscp client.

Please suggest.

Note : we use ppk and asc (pgp encrypted) file to connect to sftp server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with [SSH SFTP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) sampler in order to test upload/download speed of your SFTP server from either cloud or on-premise locations.

JMeter allows you to execute actions in parallel and measure response times for different workloads (number of concurrent threads, different file size, etc.)

See [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) article for more details on configuring JMeter for SFTP server load testing.

You can compare the numbers provided by JMeter with the numbers you get using winscp client, this way you will be able to state whether it is server or client issue. Also it may be something in between (router, proxy, load balancer, whatever).